# Apply ng-class only on the element that was clicked on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class, angular-ng-class

I want to apply the `ng-class` only on the `button/element` that was clicked on, how would I do that?

**JS file:**

```
var classApp = angular.module('classApp', []);
classApp.controller('classCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = false;

    $scope.activeButton = function() { 
       $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;         
    }  
});
```

**HTML file:**

```
<div ng-app="classApp" ng-controller="classCtrl">
    <button class="button" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-click="activeButton()" type="button">Click Me to Toggle Class</button> 

    <button class="button" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-click="activeButton()" type="button">Click Me to Toggle Class</button> 
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjNyNe

Comment: A simple solution: create an array to hold status of each button.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

The controller:

```
classApp.controller('classCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = [false, false];

    $scope.activeButton = function (index) {     
        $scope.isActive[index] = !$scope.isActive[index];         
    }   
});
```

And the html:

```
<div ng-app="classApp" ng-controller="classCtrl">
    <button class="button" ng-class="{'active': isActive[0]}" ng-click="activeButton(0)" type="button">Click Me to Toggle Class</button> 

    <button class="button" ng-class="{'active': isActive[1]}" ng-click="activeButton(1)" type="button">Click Me to Toggle Class</button> 
</div>
```

**EDIT:** My solution works but [@Shashank Agrawal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179182/apply-ng-class-only-on-the-element-that-was-clicked-on/#answer-34179373) is better and cleaner.

Comment: Hi user3632710, thank you for your answer. I like your answer more, however I want to do this without passing in the index number into my button html tags. I would ideally want to use the "this" keyword and set it to the element that was clicked on...sorry I am a newbie to AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the uses of Angular Directives.
Instead of maintaining various variables, you can use a simple directive:

```
app.directive('clickActive', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                element.toggleClass("active");
                if (attr.moreClasses) {
                    // Optionally toggle more classes if passed
                    element.toggleClass(attr.moreClasses);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="classApp" ng-controller="classCtrl">
  <button class="button" click-active type="button">Click Me to Toggle Class</button> 

   <button class="button" click-active type="button">Click Me to Toggle Class</button> 
</div>
```

Optionally, pass more classes to toggle like:

```
<button class="button" click-active more-classes="foo bar" type="button">Click Me to Toggle Class</button>
```

Comment: Maybe `element.toggleClass("active")` would fit better?

Comment: Yup, changed that. Thank you @user3632710